# Querying optional fields in Elasticsearch

Tags: elasticsearch

I have an ES type **courses** with 2 optional fields **trainer** and **trainingCompany** in such a way that in each document we have a *trainer* or a *trainingCompany* **not both**.

I tried this query to filter courses by trainers and/or training companies:

```
"query": {
    "bool": {
      "must_not": [
        {
          "terms": {
            "trainingCompany.slug": [
              "company-slug"
            ]
          }
        },
        {
          "terms": {
            "trainer.slug": [
              "trainer-slug"
            ]
          }
        }
      ]
    }
  }
```

But, I am getting all the documents in return.
I thought that I need an **exists** to check if each field exists, but still unable to figure it out.

Here is a sample course if needed:

```
    {
              "title": "title",
              "description": "description",
              "slug": "slug",
              "duration": 10,
              "language": "EN",
              "price": 1500,
              "trainingCompany": {
                "name": "The Bridge",
                "slug": "The-Bridge",
            }
}
{
          "title": "title",
          "description": "description",
          "slug": "slug",
          "duration": 1,
          "language": "FR",
          "price": 500,
          "trainer": {
            "firstname": "Jemli",
            "lastname": "Fathi",
            "slug": "Jemli-Fathi",
            "photo": "url"
          }
        }
```

Comment: Can you share one document that should not match and one that should match the query?

Comment: @Val I edited my question

Comment: So those two documents should match, right?

Comment: @Val No just a sample data

Comment: Please read my first comment again. If we are to figure it out, we need all the info we can get to sort things out.

Comment: @Val Yes I need documents having trainer/training-company slugs not matching those mentioned in the query

Comment: Then show us a document that match the query but shouldn't match.

Comment: @Val {
          "title": "title",
          "description": "description",
          "slug": "slug",
          "duration": 1,
          "language": "FR",
          "price": 500,
          "trainer": {
            "firstname": "X",
            "lastname": "Y",
            "slug": "trainer-slug",
            "photo": "xurl"
          }
        }

Comment: Ok, what about the mapping of those documents?

Comment: @Val You find here the complete mapping of the courses type: https://drive.google.com/open?id=0B2S5amMpeE6QUEdweE9CNDQ0T2c

Comment: Ok then what happens if you use `trainingCompany.slug.keyword` and `trainer.slug.keyword` instead?

Comment: @Val that's correct. I forgot the ES keyword field... Can you please post it as an answer, so I can accept it

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to your mapping, you should use the `keyword` sub-fields like this:

```
"query": {
    "bool": {
      "must_not": [
        {
          "terms": {
            "trainingCompany.slug.keyword": [
              "company-slug"
            ]
          }
        },
        {
          "terms": {
            "trainer.slug.keyword": [
              "trainer-slug"
            ]
          }
        }
      ]
    }
  }
```